# How to iterate multiple sublists and add two elements in a row from a sublist to a list?

Tags: python, list

I have these sublists with books based on book genres:

```
sci_fi = ["Dune", "Fahrenhefgvit 451", "Ender's Game", "Hypterion", "The Foundation Vol.3","The Foundation Vol.2","The Foundation Vol.1","1984"]
fantasy = ["The Wise Man's Fear", "A Clash of Kings", "Malazan Book of the Fallen","The Name of the Wind","Lord of the Rings","A Game of Thrones"]
crime_fiction = ["Murder on the Orient Express","The Cartel","The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo","The Cuckoo's Calling","The Godfather"]
comics = ["The Avengers Vol.3","Spiderman vol.16", "Ghost Rider vol.2", "Spiderman vol.15","John Constantine vol.5", "Batman vol.13","Green Arrow vol.1"]
```

Now, I would like to create a list containing these books that will be the order that the books will be read, based on the following criteria:

1. We don't want to read 2 books from the same genre in a row (if it can be avoided).
2. Except for comics, we want to read 2 in a row.

The lists are different sizes, therefore the books will added until the list has been iterated. When the books from one genre run out, books from another genre can be recommended.

An example of a possible output would be:

```
['Dune', 'Murder on the Orient Express', "The Wise Man's Fear", 'The Avengers Vol.3',"Spiderman vol.16", 'Fahrenhefgvit 451', 'The Cartel', 'A Clash of Kings', "Ghost Rider vol.2", "Spiderman vol.15", "Ender's Game", 'The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo', 'Malazan Book of the Fallen', 'Hypterion', "The Cuckoo's Calling", 'The Name of the Wind', "John Constantine vol.5", "Batman vol.13", 'The Foundation Vol.3', 'The Godfather', 'Lord of the Rings', 'Green Arrow vol.1', 'The Foundation Vol.2', 'A Game of Thrones', 'The Foundation Vol.1', '1984']
```

Comment: for the 2nd rule. If you say they should be added twice in a row. Does that mean it has to be also adjacent elements in the `comics` list or are they picked randomly from the list twice?

Comment: it can be picked randomly from the comics list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I still can't understand the problem description. It doesn't appear that there are twice as many comics as there are books of the other kinds. What should happen when you run out?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the problem description. When the comics run out, another book from another genre will be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your data to an example data to make it more readable. Don't know if it is a very efficient approach but it works the way you want (IIUC).

Basically you shuffle your lists so you have random order and then loop through it with your rules.

```
import random
import itertools

sci = ['A', 'B', 'C']
fan = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
comics = ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']

rndm_sci = random.sample(sci, len(sci))
rndm_fan = random.sample(fan, len(fan))
rndm_com = random.sample(comics, len(comics))
print('rndm_sci: ', rndm_sci)
print('rndm_fan: ', rndm_fan)
print('rndm_com: ', rndm_com)

result=[]
for sci,fan,com in itertools.zip_longest(rndm_sci,rndm_fan,itertools.zip_longest(rndm_com[::2], rndm_com[1::2])):
    if com is not None:
        result.extend([sci, fan, *com])
    else:
        result.extend([sci, fan])
result = list(filter(None, result))
print('\nresult: ', result)
```

Output:

```
rndm_sci:  ['A', 'B', 'C']
rndm_fan:  ['F', 'G', 'H', 'E', 'D']
rndm_com:  ['M', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'N', 'I', 'O']

result:  ['A', 'F', 'M', 'J', 'B', 'G', 'K', 'L', 'C', 'H', 'N', 'I', 'E', 'O', 'D']
```